# How to use preprocess field to style radio buttons

Tags: entities, theming

Trying to set up a `preprocess_field`.I have list field by radio buttons and I want to override the output like this:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-event-status field-type-list-text field-label-hidden pull-right margin-left margin-bottom">
   <div class="field-items">
       <div class="field-item even">
         <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-success" title="" data-original-title="The event has been confirmed and will proceed at the specified date and time.">
         <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Confirmed event</button>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you have to use CSS3 or any jQuery library to style radio button like this.

Comment: I just use Bootstrap framework and this is tooltip.js for popup text. Look here (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHY-M0Xc9qc) in 7:40min talk for the use preprocess_field..